# Submit form information with multiple checkboxes/select menus

Tags: javascript, html, sql-server, coldfusion

I wanted to know if it was possible to have the form on this fiddle come out onto the database like this after the user hits submit once.

```
+------+------+----------+
| Name | Meal | Quantity |
+------+------+----------+
| Adam | Beef |        2 |
| Adam | Pork |        1 |
| Adam | Lamb |        3 |
+------+------+----------+
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f8zyakvj/1/

I know that through multi selects, all the information you select is sent through as an array, but for checkboxes, how can I make it so that the information is sent in a similar fashion. When I check off the top 3 boxes, and alert the value of food to see what I get, all I ever got is "1" no matter which box I check off.

I was hoping it would be as easy as the multi select where I could do something like this for the cfm

```
<cfloop list="#form.meal#, #form.quantity#" index="currMeal, currQuant">
    <cfquery name="Add" datasource="food"> 
       INSERT INTO Log (Name, Meal, Quantity)
       VALUES ( 
         <cfqueryparam value="#Form.Name#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
         <cfqueryparam value="#currMeal#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
         <cfqueryparam value="#currQuant#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
       )
    </cfquery>
</cfloop>
```

Any help on the issue would be appreciated.

Comment: Multi selects and checkboxes act the same way.  You either get a comma delimited list of everything selected, or you get nothing, not even an empty string.  This assumes, of course, that all your checkboxes have the same name.  Your statement about information being sent as an array is not correct.

Comment: Could you explain how they act the same way? For the multi select menu, I could do something like alert($('select#meal').val()) and it would give me a value of 2, 3, 4 assuming I checked off the bottom 3. When I try to do the same for the checkboxes, assuming $('input#meal').val() is correct, all I get is 1
@DanBracuk

Comment: Dan is talking about the behavior of a basic form POST (no javascript). While you are talking about the behavior of the jQuery javascript library. Two totally different things.  Side note, I realize this is probably a simplified example, but in case it is not ... junction tables normally store id's. If the source of "meal" and/or "name" is another db table, you should insert the MealID/NameID instead, and change the cfsqltype to match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your form elements do not have names, so the values won't be posted to your form action page
2. For your select drop downs, use the name to put the value corresponding to the meal checkbox so you can easily look it up - e.g. `<input type="checkbox" value="3" name="meal">` would be paired with `<select name="quantity_3">`
3. Your insert query was missing commas, and would have given you a SQL syntax error.

Example:

```
<form name="form" action="Submit.cfm" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="meal"> Beef
<select name="quantity_1" class="GC0">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select><br>

<input type="checkbox" value="2" name="meal"> Chicken
<select name="quantity_2" class="GC1">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select><br>

<input type="checkbox" value="3" name="meal"> Pork
<select name="quantity_3" class="GC2">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select><br>

<input type="checkbox" value="4" name="meal"> Lamb
<select name="quantity_4" class="GC3">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select><br>

Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
<button value="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Then on your processing page `submit.cfm` you can loop through FORM.meal (if it exists) and use the value of each item checked to reference the corresponding quantity field name:

```
<!--- Make sure something was checked before proceeding --->
<cfparam name="FORM.meal" default="" />

<!--- Convert the meal list to an array for looping --->
<cfset mealArray = listToArray(FORM.meal)>

<!--- Loop over the array values --->
<cfloop array="#mealArray#" index="currMeal">
    <!--- Insert into database --->
    <cfquery name="Add" datasource="food">
        INSERT INTO Log (Name, Meal, Quantity)
        VALUES (
            <cfqueryparam value="#FORM.Name#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
            ,<cfqueryparam value="#currMeal#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
            ,<cfqueryparam value="#FORM['quantity_#currMeal#']#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
        )
    </cfquery>
</cfloop>
```

Please keep in mind that you should consider wrapping your database inserts in a transaction, and/or consider a method for bulk inserting. Querying a database inside a loop is not considered best practice.

Comment: Good approach.  @khgove - As beloitdavisja mentioned above, you *must* wrap these kind of related inserts in a [transaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) to ensure data integrity. With transactions, you do not have to worry that only some of the queries will succeed. They will *all* succeed (or all fail) as a single unit.