# Inserting a dynamic amount of rows in a Coldfusion form with MySql

Tags: jquery, mysql, forms, loops, coldfusion

I have taken over a project that uses JQuery in a Coldfusion form to dynamically add rows of items for a "quote" document. I need to loop thru the form and insert each row into a MySql database in separate fields. My problem is that I need to add certain values once and others multiple times with dynamically changing names and values.
This is the form: ( I have omitted some of the fields that only need to be inserted once)

```
    <tr>
    <input id="quoteDate" name="quoteDate"  value="#rc.private.currDate#">
    <input id="quoteID" name="quoteID" value="#rc.private.quoteID#">
    </tr>
    <tr id="dummyRow" class="hidden-print" style="display:none">
    <td>                
    <input id="itemQty_" name="itemQty_" value="" class="qtyField" type="number" min="0" pattern="[0-9]*" maxlength="6" size="3">
    </td>                           
    <td>                            
<input id="itemPriceEach_" name="itemPriceEach_" class="itemPriceField" type="text" maxlength="8" value="">
    <input id="itemDesc_" name="itemDesc_" class="hidden" value="">
    </td>
```

The last 3 inputs are the ones that are added dynamically with the following jQuery:

```
   nr = $newRow;
    $newRow.removeAttr("id");
    $newRow.find("td:nth-child(1)").empty().append( item.itemCode );
    $newRow.find("td:nth-child(2)").empty().append( item.description );
    $newRow.find("input[id^=itemQty_]").val(1).attr("id", "itemQty_" + item.itemCode) .attr("name", "itemQty_" + item.itemCode);
    $newRow.find("input[id^=itemPriceEach_]").val( accounting.formatMoney(item.price) ).attr("id", "itemPriceEach_" + item.itemCode).attr("name", "itemPriceEach_" + item.itemCode);
    $newRow.find("input[id^=itemDesc_]").val( item.description ).attr("id","itemDesc_" + item.description).attr("name","itemDesc_" + item.description);
```

How can I loop thru only the needed inputs to insert them with different names and values. What I have built already inserts all of the values into one field in the table.

```
<cfquery name="addNewQuote" datasource="inv">
            INSERT INTO inv.quotesaves
                (quoteID, cNumber, quoteDate, itemcode, itemQty_, itemPriceEach_, itemDesc_,fetqty, fetPriceEach)
            VALUES(
                <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#arguments.quoteID#">,
                <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#arguments.cNumber#">,
                <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#arguments.quoteDate#">,
                <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#arguments.itemCode#">,
                <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#arguments.itemQty_#">,
                <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#arguments.itemPriceEach_#">,
                <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#arguments.itemDesc_#"> )               
</cfquery>
```

This is a dump of my form.

```
-CNUMBER    ZZ1753

-FIELDNAMES QUOTEDATE,QUOTEID,CNUMBER,ITEMCODE,ITEMDESC_51769,ITEMQTY_51769,ITEMPRICEEACH_51769,ITEMQTY_015,ITEMPRICEEACH_015,ITEMDESC_LABOR,ITEMQTY_011,ITEMPRICEEACH_011,ITEMDESC_OIL,ITEMQTY_,ITEMPRICEEACH_,ITEMDESC_,ADDITEMCODE

-ITEMCODE   51769

-ITEMDESC_  [empty string]

-ITEMDESC_51769 [empty string]

-ITEMDESC_LABOR labor

-ITEMDESC_OIL   oil

-ITEMPRICEEACH_ [empty string]

-ITEMPRICEEACH_011  $3.00

-ITEMPRICEEACH_015  $15.00

-ITEMPRICEEACH_51769    $157.70

-ITEMQTY_   [empty string]

-ITEMQTY_011    1

-ITEMQTY_015    3

-ITEMQTY_51769  2

-QUOTEDATE  October 08, 2015

-QUOTEID    82103808

action  retailquote.quotesave
origPage    RetailQuote.quoteSave
```

What I need is for each item beginning with "itemQty_" and "itemPriceEach_" to be added to the table in separate fields. So one row will contain "quoteID", the value of "itemQty_" and value of "itemPriceEach_"

So after much trial and tribulation, I finally figured out a good way to do this using a cfloop and ListGetAt. Seems to work perfectly this way.

```
<cftransaction>
    <cfloop from="1" to="#ListLen(form.itemQty_)#" index="i">
        <cfquery name="quoteAddOns"  datasource="inv">
            INSERT INTO inv.quoteAddOns
                (quoteID, itemDesc_,itemQty_, itemPriceEach_, fetqty, fetPriceEach)
            VALUES(
            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#arguments.quoteID#">,
            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#ListGetAt(arguments.itemDesc_,i)#">,
            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#ListGetAt(arguments.itemQty_,i)#">,
            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#ListGetAt(arguments.itemPriceEach_,i)#">,
            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#ListGetAt(arguments.fetQty#">,
            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#arguments.fetPriceEach#">)
    </cfquery>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: Can you please [update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33018715/edit) with a sample of the actual form field names submitted? `CFdump` the `FORM` (or `arguments` scope) on your action page.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure I follow the naming conventions and relationships. Some of the names are generated by appending an itemCode suffix (51769): ie ITEM_QTY_51769, ITEMPRICEEACH_51769, etcetera. What about the others? Examples: A) No suffix `ITEMPRICEEACH_` B) "011" suffix: `ITEMPRICEEACH_011` C) "015" suffix: `ITEMPRICEEACH_015` D) Other suffix: `ITEMDESC_LABOR` ....  Are these all supposed to be linked to the same itemCode - 51769? Using the field names above, how many records do you expect to be inserted into the db?

Comment: My answer to the following question might help you.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32970739/creating-a-survey-using-coldfusion-stuck-on-the-table-data-insert

Comment: That is one possibility.  However, I am curious about the naming convention... The relationships are not obvious from the names alone. You may want to consider changing them to make them more intuitive.

Comment: each suffix is linked to an itemcode. The itemcodes come from corresponding tables. The names are appended with the jQuery .attr command. I am not sure why there are entries for each with empty strings. To be specific: 51769 is for the sale of a tire. The others are for miscellaneous charges for the installation of the tire. 
The trouble that I am hiving is that I have no idea how many records will be inserted. Some quotes might have 0, some might have 5.

Comment: I agree on the naming conventions, but I was just trying to build off of what was already made before I took over the project.

Comment: So there can be multiple itemCode fields? Whatever the naming convention, you need to somehow link each "set" of fields to a related itemCode. If the form contains multiple fields named "itemCode", the values will be submitted as a CSV list ie `form.itemCode = "51769,51770,51784,..."`. A simple way to link the related fields is to use the itemCode as a suffix ie `itemQty_51769,itemPriceXX_51769,itemDesc_51769`. On the action page, simply loop through the `form.itemCode` list and extract the related values for each code using associative array notation: ie `form["itemQty_"& currrentItemCode]`.

Comment: The CSV list is one of the solutions that I have come up with. By removing the .attr all of the fields are simply called"itemQty_" and "itemPriceEach_"

Comment: Not quite what I meant. I am assuming the form does contain multiple itemCodes (you did not confirm that).  When dealing with an unknown number of related "sets", the most common approaches are A) [Use a consecutive numeric suffix and loop from=1 to=totalNumber](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14857537/creating-a-dynamic-form-but-how-to-do-the-query/14860727#14860727) to extract the values OR B)  [Use an ID suffix and loop through the list of ID's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32231877/submit-form-information-with-multiple-checkboxes-select-menus).

Comment: @Leigh, You were correct about the looping and the suffix. I just needed to take it a step a farther and use ListGetAt to assign all of the elements with the proper names. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @WesLoflin - The problem with using the "same named fields" approach is that the code will break if any of the field *values* contain the delimiter ie a comma.  Take another look at the two examples above. Notice, all of the field names are unique? For CF10+, another option is to use the Application setting `this.sameformfieldsasarray`. This setting avoids the list gotcha mentioned by submitting form fields with the same name as arrays, instead of delimited strings.

Answer (score 0):

(Too long for comments)

The downside to using the "same named fields" approach is that the code will break if any of the values contain the list delimiter (ie comma) which is not uncommon. One of the common alternatives to lists, is [generating unique field names by appending a numeric ID value as a suffix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32231877/submit-form-information-with-multiple-checkboxes-select-menus):

For example, say you have three itemCode's "51769, 51775, 51782", simply append each code as a suffix on all of the *related* fields (qty, desc, price, etcetera), ie

- itemPrice_**51769**, itemDesc_**51769**,itemQty_**51769**,...
- itemPrice_**51775**, itemDesc_**51775**,itemQty_**51775**,...
- itemPrice_**51782**, itemDesc_**51782**,itemQty_**51782**,...

To extract the submitted values, simply loop through the form.itemCode list, and use associative array notation to access the related fields dynamically:

```
<cfloop list="#form.itemCode#" index="currItemCode">

   <!--- extract the fields for current itemCode --->
   <cfset itemQty   = FORM["itemQty_"& currItemCode]>
   <cfset itemPrice = FORM["itemPrice_"& currItemCode]>
   <cfset itemDesc  = FORM["itemDesc_"& currItemCode]>
   ...

   <!--- for debugging only ---> 
   <cfoutput>
   DEBUG: Current itemCode = #currentID# 
          itemQty   = #itemQty#
          itemPrice = #itemPrice#
          itemDesc  = #itemDesc#
     ... <br>
   </cfoutput>


   ... now use the values in your query ....
</cfloop>
```

If you must stick with all "same-name-fields", a better option might be the new CF10+ [Application setting `this.sameformfieldsasarray`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/application-cfc-reference/application-variables.html). Fields having the the same name will be passed as an array, instead of a list, which avoids the delimiter issues. Simply loop through the generated arrays.